# How to set random colour in a discord.js embed

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, discord.js

I have a discord bot and it works perfectly. My objective is that when I send the `>help` message, the bot chooses a random colour for the embed and sends it.

This is the configuration file for my bot called `config.json`

```js
{
  "token": "Token Here",
  "prefix": ">",
  "genChannel": "channel id",
  "genCooldown": "1000",
  "color": {
      "green": "0x57F287",
      "yellow": "0xFEE75C",
      "red": "0xED4245",
      "default": "0x5865F2"
  },
  "command": {
      "notfound_message": true,
      "error_message": true
  }
}
```

Comment: Instead of posting your config.json file, you could post your current code to show what you have tried so far

Answer (score 0):

In `discord.js`, you can pass a colour argument as a string. More on that in: [discord.js docs on embed colour](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/ColorResolvable). To use a random colour, you may use the following:

```js
{
//...
    "color": {
        "green": "0x57F287",
        "yellow": "0xFEE75C",
        "red": "0xED4245",
        "default": "0x5865F2",
        "random": "RANDOM"
    },
//...
}
```

You parse it into the embed just like any other embed colour hex or RGB array. It's a good idea to check out on the docs and guide.

Comment: oh trank you :)